# In anglularjs, how to check that "Spring-boot" server session timed out, without reseting this timeout to its max?

Tags: angularjs, session, spring-boot

I would like to regulary check if the server session timed-out, to automatically log out users when no server session remains.

- I can't rely on the cookie created by setting `server.session.cookie.max-age=` because I can't read it in chrome.
- I also can't rely on a purely client solution that would be
  desynchronised with the server session

How can I check from client-side that the server session timed out since any call to the server triggers a reset of session timeout to its max ?

Can I prevent any URL to reset this timeout ?

Would you have any other idea ?

I setup my angularjs/Spring-boot application with 
a `server.session.timeout=` in application.properties, 
and the following session configuration:

```
http.sessionManagement()
        .maximumSessions(1)
        .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);
```

Versions used: 
 - Angularjs 1.5.5
 - Spring-Boot 1.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to :

- Setup a cookie myself on client-side using ngCookies
- Maitain its timeout workflow myself 
  (by reseting its timeout on each server call)
- Maintain a copy of its timeout in its value.
- Watching when it disapears and loging out in such case

Note that $rootScope.authenticate(); is called before every user action. 
This is to check if server sesson is still active,
to then log-out the user if false or reset the cookie timeout if true.

Here is the code:

```
$scope.deleteTimeoutCookie = function () {
    $cookies.remove("OptimaClientTimeout");
}
$scope.resetTimeoutCookie = function () {
            console.log("setCookie");
            var delayInMinutes=1;
            var maxAge = new Date();
            console.log("max-age="+maxAge);
            //now.setDate(now.getDate() + 7);
            maxAge.setMinutes(maxAge.getMinutes() + delayInMinutes);
            console.log("next max-age="+maxAge);

            $cookies.put("OptimaClientTimeout", maxAge, {
                expires: maxAge
            });
}

//keep it for debug:      
//    var check = function() {
//      console.log("check ");
//      console.log("authenticated: "+$rootScope.authenticated);
//      console.log("JSESSIONID:"+$cookies.get('JSESSIONID'));
//      console.log("OptimaClientTimeout:"+$cookies.get("OptimaClientTimeout"));
//      
//    }
//    $interval(function(){  check(); },10000);

//Appear to be necessary for the following $watch(er) to receive the change event ! :
$interval(function(){},10000);
$rootScope.$watch( function(){ return $cookies.get("OptimaClientTimeout");} , function(newValue,oldValue) {
             console.log('being watched oldValue:', oldValue, 'newValue:', newValue);
             console.log('authenticated: ' + $rootScope.authenticated);
             if((typeof oldValue != 'undefined') && (typeof newValue == 'undefined')){
                 $rootScope.logout();
             }
      },true);

      $rootScope.logout = function() {
        console.log("rootScope logout called 1/2"); 
            $http.post('logout', {}).finally(function() {// /logout post
                                                            // implemented by
                                                            // default by spring
                                                            // security
            console.log("js logout called"); 
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            $scope.deleteTimeoutCookie();
            $location.path("/");
          });
      }

      self.logout = function() {
          console.log("app logout called "); 
          $rootScope.logout();
      };

      $scope.deleteTimeoutCookie();
        $rootScope.authenticate = function(credentials, callback) {
              console.log("authentication Client user is "+$rootScope.username);
            var headers = credentials ? {authorization : "Basic "
                + crossb_btoa(credentials.username + ":" + credentials.password)
            } : {};

            $http.get('user', {headers : headers}).then(function(response) {

              if (response.data.name) {
                $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                $rootScope.username=response.data.name;
                $scope.resetTimeoutCookie();
                console.log("authentication OK for "+response.data.name);

                //$cookies.put("STO", value, [options]);

              } else {
                $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                $rootScope.username="";
                console.log("authentication ko for unknown user ");
                $rootScope.logout();
              }
              callback && callback();
            }, function() {
              $rootScope.authenticated = false;
              $rootScope.username="";      
              console.log("authentication ko");
              $rootScope.logout();
              callback && callback();
            });

          };

      $rootScope.authenticate();
```

Comment: Note the weird necessity to call $interval even with no action, for the $watch method to be warned of cookie update !